# Attaching more than one file to an email

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I have been struggling with this for a while and I could not find the answer for my problem.
The scenario is the following:
 One web application using play framework lunched on Google app engine. Attempting to attach 2 pdf file to the email and send it. With one file it is working perfectly. With two I get errors.
Here is the code:
    package app;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.MimeType;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;


public class Mailer {

    public static void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body, byte[]     pdf1, byte[] pdf2)
    throws AddressException, MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myAddress@gmail.com", "John Smith"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to, to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(body);

        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
        mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

        //Attaching first pdf
        MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachment.setFileName("pdf1.pdf");
        DataSource src = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdf1, "application/pdf"); 
        attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(src));
        mp.addBodyPart(attachment);


        //Attaching second pdf
        attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachment.setFileName("pdf2.pdf");
        src = new ByteArrayDataSource(badgePDF, "application/pdf"); 
        attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(src));
        mp.addBodyPart(attachment);


        msg.setContent(mp);

        Transport.send(msg);
    }


}
```

Unfortunately I have no error message even if I print the caught exception's stackTrack, but I my guess is that there is an issue with the DataSource object. I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FileDataSource` for your `DataSource` type instead of using `ByteArrayDataSource`. Try the following:

```
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);    

File[] attachments = new File[2];
atts[1] = new File("pdf1.pdf");
atts[2] = new File("pdf2.pdf");
for( int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++ ) {
   messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
   FileDataSource fileDataSource =new FileDataSource(attachments[i]);
   messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
   messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachments[i].getName());
   mp.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

}

msg.setContent(mp);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: The pdf is generated by the application and is not saved on the server as a file because I cannot save files on google app engine, that's why the data is in a byte array.

Comment: Have you tried using [MultiPartEmail](http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/MultiPartEmail.html)

Comment: As far as I know I cannot use org.apache.commons.

Comment: I really need this to be sorted out be I still haven't found the solution. Can anyone help me out?